# delegate with generic type

Tags: c#, function, generic-programming

I have a delegate `public delegate void ObserverCallback<T>(T value, string key);` which I want the `value` parameter to be whatever I want.

I have an **ObserverCallback** property in my class `public ObserverCallback Callback;` which *obviously* gives me this error `error CS0305: Using the generic type 'Observer.ObserverCallback<T>' requires 1 type arguments`. At this point, I do not know what type will be the parameter.

I would like to fix that error and to be able to pass a function through a contructor **e.g. :**

- `public Observer(ObserverCallback<???> callback)`
- `private void ACallbackFunction(Player value)`
- `var obs = new Observer(ACallbackFunction)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observer class has to be generic, and then you can use that parameter in the constructor:

```
public class Observer<T>
{
    public Observer(ObserverCallback<T> callback)
    {    

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var obs = new Observer<Player>(ACallbackFunction);
```

If you need to use `Observer` as a non-generic, you could inherit from a non-generic base or implement a common interface. The caveat here is that the methods using the class generic argument `T` won't be available unless you explicitly cast it back to `Observable<T>`:

```
public class Observer
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class Observer<T>
{
    public Observer(ObserverCallback<T> callback)
    {
    }
}

var observerList = new List<Observer>();
observerList.Add(new Observer<Player>(ACallbackFunction));
observerList.ForEach(o => o.SomeMethod());
```

or

```
public interface IObserver
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class Observer<T>: IObserver
{
    public Observer(ObserverCallback<T> callback)
    {
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}

var observerList = new List<IObserver>();
observerList.Add(new Observer<Player>(ACallbackFunction));
observerList.ForEach(o => o.SomeMethod());
```

Note that this generic argument `T` will be available to any method in the class, so you don't have to write `public void MyMethod<T>(T value)` (which declares a generic argument `T`), you can then just write `public void MyMethod(T value)` because the generic argument is at the class level.

Comment: I have in another class named **Observable** a list of Observers `readonly List<Observer<T>> observers = new List<Observer<T>>();` which now needs `<T>`s. So that means that **Observable** has also to be generic but I want my list to have multiple Observer types since I want my callbacks to have any parameter types.

Comment: Depending on how you want to use it, you might look at a non-generic base class, or implement a common interface.

Comment: That is what I first tried. I was using `public delegate void ObserverCallback(IObserverValue value, string key)` where Player was implementing `interface IObserverValue { }`. But I was getting this error `error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Observer.ObserverCallback'` with `private void ACallbackFunction(Player value)`

Comment: I mean you might want to make `Observer<T>` inherit from a base class, or implement a common interface. I've updated my answer to demonstrate both.

Comment: Do I need to do this? `public ObserverCallback<T> Callback;` inside `class Observer<T>`

Comment: Also, when I try to instantiate Observer having a `readonly List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>();` it asks 1 type argument, which in my case is IObserverValue, and it says that I can't convert **Observer<IObserverValue>** to **IObserverValue**

Comment: @JuZDePeche I don't know if you need to do that - that's down to the specifics of your project. You presumably need to store it somewhere though.

Comment: As for the second thing, the list itself doesn't require a generic argument for IObserver, unless you also made the interface generic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203281/discussion-between-juzdepeche-and-john-reinstatemonica).